# How to integrate this function using arccos?

Tags: calculus, integration, indefinite-integrals

> $$-\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2}}$$

I know I have to use the formulas for things like arccos and arccsin, but I don't know how to get it in that form.

Comment: Is this your question or $$I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\color{red}{a}+x^3-x^2}}$$ as you wrote it in the original post ?

Answer (score 2):

I assume $x > 1$. Then your integral has the form

$$- \int \frac{\mathrm dx}{x\sqrt{x - 1}}.$$

Now let $u = \sqrt{x - 1}, \ \mathrm dx = 2 \sqrt{x - 1}\ \mathrm du$. This substitution leads to

$$- 2 \int \frac{\mathrm du}{u^2 + 1}.$$

But this is a standard integral, which evaluates to

$$- 2 \arctan(u) + C.$$

Undoing the substitution gives

$$\fbox{$-2\arctan(\sqrt{x - 1}) + C$.}$$

Comment: What about $a$ ?

Comment: What do you mean by $a$?

Comment: As far as I know, the question is $I=\int \frac{dx}{\sqrt{\color{red}{a}+x^3-x^2}}$

Comment: Why did you change the question ?

Comment: OP changed the question himself. See the edit history.

Answer (score 0):

The integrand is $-1/(x\sqrt(1-x))$. Let $u^2=x$. $2udu=dx$.

=> integral $-2/(u\sqrt(u^2-1)) du = -2\text{arcsec}(u)+ C$

So our answer is $-2\text{arcsec}(\sqrt(x))+C$.

Comment: What about $a$ ?

Comment: There is no 'a' in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Let $x = \frac1{t^2}$. Then,

$$-\int \frac{\mathrm dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2}}=\int \frac {2dt}{\sqrt{1-t^2}}=-2\text{arccos} (t)+C$$

Comment: Would you like to go to the initial question ? Cheers :-)

Answer (score 0):

Start with $x=\sec^2 u$

$$\int\frac{dx}{\sqrt{x^3-x^2}}=\int\frac{dx}{x\sqrt{x-1}}=2\int \ du=2u=2\sec^{-1}(\sqrt{x})+C$$